# Scroller move to top of table when remove row from data table jquery plugin

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I am using data table in my angular js Application as angular Directive and passing data to it using "=" scope.When remove row using row.remove.draw() scroller moves to top of table.
This is my code:

```
var row = $scope.table.row($(this).parents('tr'));
row.remove.draw();
```

I checked it further even if i comment row.remove.draw() its removes row.So i guess its due to table redraw with new data.Because i use two way binding on data.
Data table Initialization:

```
$('#example')DataTable({"aaData": $scope.list,});
```

Directive Call:

```
<data-table list="data"></data-table>
```

Scope of list in directive:

```
list:"="
```

Comment: Please post some sample code what you've tried so far to help you better..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row.remove.draw(false);` to stay on the same page.  Checkout the [draw() API doc](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()).

Comment: By using this option the scroller issue is fixed.thanks